# Should I wrap all my pages with ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know it seems dummy question but I can't solve this simple question my mind. Should I wrap all my pages with `ScrollView` to support all different screen sizes?

As I told, I resize components for screen sizes and resolutions but I know some pages won't show them properly at last.

I mean, smaller screen sizes may not show whole content of my page even though I resize them for their resolution and size so should I put all of my pages in `ScrollView` to make them able to use whole page?

If answer is no, then what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's what you should do. If content of your page cannot be contained in device dimensions, you have to let users to scroll and view them rather than compress and make them fit to the screen which will definitely harm user experience.

Also that is not necessary for all your screens. Pages which don't have much details, can be wrapped with a view.